# Set custom attribute using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom, dynatree

I am using The DynaTree (https://code.google.com/p/dynatree) but I am having some problems and hoping someone can help..

I am displaying the tree on the page like below:

```html
<div id="tree">
    <ul>
        <li class="folder">Outputs
            <ul>
                <li id="item1" data="icon: 'base.gif', url: 'page1.htm', target: 'AccessPage'">Item 1 Title</li>
                <li id="item2" data="icon: 'base.gif', url: 'page2.htm', target: 'AccessPage'">Item 2 Title</li>
                <li id="item3" data="icon: 'base.gif', url: 'page3.htm', target: 'AccessPage'">Item 3 Title</li>
                <li id="item4" data="icon: 'base.gif', url: 'page4.htm', target: 'AccessPage'">Item 4 Title</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

However I am trying to change the icon on a item no matter if it's selected or not only using **JavaScript**.

the new icon I want to use is base2.gif

I have tried using the following but it don't seem to work:

```js
document.getElementById('item1').data = "icon: 'base2.gif', url: 'output.htm', target: 'AccessPage', output: '1'";
```

anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: the keyword `data` is a prefix. You should be using `data-you-attribute-name`

Answer (score 251):

Use the `setAttribute` method:

```
document.getElementById('item1').setAttribute('data', "icon: 'base2.gif', url: 'output.htm', target: 'AccessPage', output: '1'");
```

But you really should be using data followed with a dash and with its property, like:

```
<li ... data-icon="base.gif" ...>
```

And to do it in JS use the `dataset` property:

```
document.getElementById('item1').dataset.icon = "base.gif";
```

Comment: The dataset property might be useful if only browsers compliant with HTML5 are considered, but that is a short list and wider support is required for the general web. I'd stick to using *setAttribute* for now.

Comment: still can't get it to work by using document.getElementById('item1').setAttribute('data', "icon: 'base2.gif', url: 'output.htm', target: 'AccessPage', output: '1'");

Comment: What exactly are you doing in your code that makes you realize it's not working?

Comment: I have added the code and added a alert at the end (so it will alart when the code is done), and I can also see the icon not changing. (when I remove the code is see my alart display, so i know there is somthing wrong with the code I just added.)

Comment: IE <= 8 does not support setAttribute

Comment: For my use case, I found that I don't even need to instantiate the index data attribute in any way. Just declare and assign a value to it. 

`[documentElement].dataset.index = 0;`

Then get it similarly like

`[documentElement].dataset.index` which would return 0

Comment: If you're anal about performance I would stick to `setAttribute()` for now. See [jsPerf](https://jsperf.com/html5-dataset-vs-native-setattribute).

Comment: @thdoan, So setAttribute is better than directly modify dataset? According to MDN  document, I thought the dataset can't directly modify,  but when to try It can work, so... I don't know what method is the correct way. haha.

Answer (score 70):

Please use dataset

```
var article = document.querySelector('#electriccars'),
    data = article.dataset;

// data.columns -> "3"
// data.indexnumber -> "12314"
// data.parent -> "cars"
```

so in your case for setting data:

```
getElementById('item1').dataset.icon = "base2.gif";
```

Comment: Also (when appropriate), use camelCase to refer to hyphenated names (bracketed strings fail).

Comment: https://jsperf.com/html5-dataset-vs-native-setattribute This suggested method is a lot slower

Answer (score 30):

For people coming from Google, this question is not about data attributes - OP added a non-standard attribute to their HTML object, and wondered how to set it.

However, you should not add custom attributes to your properties - you *should* use [data attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) - e.g. OP should have used `data-icon`, `data-url`, `data-target`, etc.

In any event, it turns out that the way you set these attributes via JavaScript is the same for both cases. Use:

```
ele.setAttribute(attributeName, value);
```

to change the given attribute `attributeName` to `value` for the DOM element `ele`.

For example:

```
document.getElementById("someElement").setAttribute("data-id", 2);
```

Note that you can also use `.dataset` to set the values of data attributes, but as @racemic points out, it is [62% slower](https://jsperf.com/html5-dataset-vs-native-setattribute) (at least in Chrome on macOS at the time of writing). So I would recommend using the `setAttribute` method instead.