# Can a variable be stored within an image or div tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I've managed to create a huge `div` that contains many small `div`s appended to it, so it creates a grid. My goal is to be able to store two variables within each of the smaller `div`s (tiles). Currently, I'm able to store one value within the smaller tiles by changing the `innerHTML`, however, I would like to be able to store more than just that one value.

The following is my code to create the tiles:

```
    var id = 0; // variable for generating unique id for divs
    var x = 0;  //default value within each tile


    function cdiv(ele) {
      var div = document.createElement("div");
      div.innerHTML = 'div' + id;
      div.id = 'div' + id++; // det unique id and increment id value
      div.style.width = "50px";
      div.style.height = "50px";
      div.style.background = "red";   //default color of tile
      div.style.color = "black";   //color of value within tile
      div.style.display = "inline-block";   //some amount of tiles per line
      div.addEventListener("click", clr);
      div.innerHTML = x;   //this is what shows inside each tile
      ele.appendChild(div);   //adds this tile to an element

    }

//my master container
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    div.style.width = "500px"; ///10 times of inner divs
    div.style["overflow-x"]= "visible"; // to show overflow
    document.body.appendChild(div);

//following function generates my grid within the above master container
    for (i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      for (b = 0; b < 10; b++) { 
        cdiv(div);
      }
    }

//following function increments the value inside the tile per click
    function clr(e) {
      var clickedElement = document.getElementById(e.currentTarget.id);
      var currentXValue = clickedElement.innerHTML;
      clickedElement.style.background = "green";
      currentXValue++
      clickedElement.innerHTML = currentXValue;
    }
```

How can I add variables to the tiles (`div`s within the large container `div`),  so that I can later call that variable and pass it onto another div to display?

I would like to have the following three variables:

- The number of clicks on the current clicked tile, as I have in my
  code above, except not to display within that tile. Merely, store it
  as a value for that tile in some variable
- X-coordinate of the tile clicked on
- Y-coordinate of the tile clicked on

Comment: If you use jQuery you could use its `.data()` method to associate any data with an element.

Comment: I've only begun learning programming and I hear a lot about jQuery but it's a bit much for me to tackle at the moment. I think I'll read up on that soon

Comment: It may be a bit much, but it's worth it, since it makes lots of things easier.

Comment: Good point. I'll do it soon. Right after I figure out this creating a data attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can create **infinite** `data-[whatever]` **attributes** to store any variables you'd like

you can then access this variable with `element.getAttribute('data-example-name');`

**here's an example:**

```js
var testElement = document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];
var result = document.getElementById('result');
result.textContent = testElement.getAttribute('data-my-tag');
```

```css
.test {
  background: blue;
  color: white;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  width: 300px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="test" data-my-tag="5">
  <h2>testing a made-up attribute, <br>
  data-my-tag = 
    <span id="result">{should be a number}</span>
  </h2>
</div>
```

same code via [jsfiddle](http://var%20testElement%20=%20document.getElementsByClassName('test')[0];%20var%20result%20=%20document.getElementById('result');%20result.textContent%20=%20testElement.getAttribute('data-my-tag');)

Comment: there's no need to go somewhere else. the code is as simple as passing a *made up attribute* and calling it with `getAttribute` later. The fiddle is just to illustrate an working example.. I'll leave the working example in the embedded editor

Comment: I know, but thank you for bringing your code into the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two ways to store information with each div:

(1) Storing a hidden `<input type="hidden" value="something" />` file in the div

(2) Adding the `data-something="Some information"` attribute to the div. Code would look like:

```
div.dataset.something = "Some information to pass along";
```

Here's more information on (2):

[Set data attribute using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286661/set-data-attribute-using-javascript)

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes

https://www.sitepoint.com/use-html5-data-attributes/

---

The data attribute can be used with many HTML tags, including `<img data-desc="Photo of a dog" />`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you can add any property (or even function) to your element. Like if you have a `div` variable for your element, you can do just

```
div.someProperty = someValue;
div.myFunction = function(...) { ... };
```

The only thing you should care about is not to overwrite some "system" property like `style` and others.

Comment: Don't add random properties to objects, they might conflict with something that will be added in a future HTML/Javascript specification. This is why `data-*` attributes were created, they're specifically for the application.

Comment: @Barmar right, thanks for the tip. Is it possible to add an attribute with object value? Limiting myself to just string values would be quite inconvenient..

Comment: Unfortunately, no,but you can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert an object/array to a string. If you use jQuery you can use its `.data()` method; it can associate arbitrary objects with elements, it stores them in an internal data structure.