# How do I highlight the parts of the image that is clicked or dragged, and save that area?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I essentially need to have a user online click drag with the mouse or fingers on a picture of the human body to highlight the selected area red. Basically they're selecting areas of the body that hurt. 
Then I need to store this information, and use it as needed.

Looking online I just seem to find how to highlight an area on hover like JQuery's maphighlight feature, which isn't what I want.

I'm very new to coding but am learning as I go along.

Comment: hint...every mouse/touch event has page coordinates. Beyond that this question is simply far too broad

Comment: Also might want to look into canvas or even image map

Comment: Hi, do you need someone to tie your shoelaces for you as well?  This question is exceptionally lazy.   You have to do your own work first.  SO is only for specific questions about existing code.  Not for you to ask for your entire work to be done or to be explained how to be done.

Answer (score -1):

There are more **[pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)** than **hover**. In this case, **active** or **visited**.

- You could simply change the selected image section to a highlighted version of the same image.
- Or add a `border` CSS property on `:visited`

To store information use either a made up **[data-[whatever]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37737694/can-a-variable-be-stored-within-an-image-or-div-tag/37737708#37737708)** attribute,
 
or use a regular JavaScript variable. 
Since you'll need JavaScript to use the given variable anyways.

There are [fancier](http://greensock.com/drawSVG) solutions.
MAP is great for selecting shapes within an image, but doesn't have a way to highlight that selection.