# Assign data-value to a href using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I'm having a problem of assigning a value to an anchor tag's data-attribute. Here is my code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("setcolor").click();
}

var color = "red";
document.getElementById("mycolor").value = color;
</script>

<a id="setcolor" class="colors" href="#" role="button" data-value="mycolor">Choose color</a>
```

I would like to set the following string value to the href above (replace 'mycolor' with 'red'):

data-value="red"

but the above is not working. Any tips are appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set data attribute using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286661/set-data-attribute-using-javascript)

Comment: So since your `var color = "red";` is outside of the onload event, it is executed immediately, without the HTML being ready. You need to add an onclick listener to the setColor a ID, and add the color changing code there

Comment: Move that color changing part inside onload function too.

Comment: The id `mycolor` does not exist.

Comment: appreciate the tips.

Comment: @DavidLee, small tip: Don't use `href="#"` if you are binding a click event to anchor tag, use `href="javascript:void(0)"` or in JavaScript level `event.preventDefault()`.

Comment: And don't forget to approve the answer which solves your problem. And vote the answers which added value to the question. :)

Answer (score 4):

You try:

```
document.getElementById("setcolor").setAttribute("data-value", color);
```

Comment: appreciate the tip.

Answer (score 2):

If you need only to change the color on click for you `<a>` tag you can consider a much more straightforward solution using only CSS, in this case a [CSS :active Selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/:active).

```css
#setcolor:active{
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<a id="setcolor" class="colors">Choose color (Click me!)</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting your code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("setcolor").click();
}

var color = "red";
var setcolor = document.getElementById("setcolor");
setcolor.dataset.value = color; //sets data-value="red"
</script>
```

sample here https://jsfiddle.net/fjchy6av/1/

Comment: appreciate the help.

Comment: @DavidLee, if this help you might consider upvoting or accepting this answer =)

Answer (score 0):

Simply update your code to,

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    var color = "red",
        setcolorLink = document.getElementById("setcolor");

    setcolorLink.setAttribute("data-value", color);
    setcolorLink.click();
  }
</script>

<a id="setcolor" class="colors" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" data-value="mycolor">Choose color</a>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1usopvda/2/

---

### Further Explaining

There are 2 ways of doing this. See the examples below, how to use `data-attribute` in JavaScript.

```
var colorLink = document.getElementById("setcolor");
```

- Using DOM's `getAttribute()` property

  ```
   var getColor = colorLink.getAttribute("data-value") //returns "mycolor"

   colorLink.setAttribute("data-value", "red") //changes "data-value" to "red"
   colorLink.removeAttribute("data-value") //removes "data-value" attribute entirely
  ```
- Using JavaScript's `dataset` property

  ```
  var getColor = colorLink.dataset.value //returns "mycolor"

  colorLink.dataset.value = 'red' //changes "data-value" to "red"
  colorLink.dataset.value = null  //removes "data-value" attribute
  ```

---

### And I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by the `click()` in the question. So if you want to change the value onclick, see the example below

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
    var color = "red",
        setcolorLink = document.getElementById("setcolor");

    setcolorLink.onclick = function(){
        this.setAttribute("data-value", color);
    };
  }
</script>

<a id="setcolor" class="colors" href="javascript:void(0)" role="button" data-value="mycolor">Choose color</a>
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/1usopvda/4/

Comment: appreciate the help.

Comment: You are most welcome @DavidLee, I updated the answer with more examples. So you can learn more. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your js usage is not correct. Try it out following
```

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
document.getElementById("setcolor").click();
}

var color = "red";
document.getElementById("setcolor").setAttribute("mycolor", color);
</script>

<a id="setcolor" class="colors" href="#" role="button" data-value="mycolor">Choose color</a>
```

```

Comment: appreciate the help