# Set certain data to firstChild "data-id" attrbute?

Tags: javascript, dom

How can I get/set the firstChild's attribute "data-id"?
I can set name and inner text of a textarea :

```
el.firstChild.name='txt_'+j;
el.firstChild.innerText = 'Textarea '+j;
```

what I am trying to do is to change "data-id' value like this (pseudocode):

```
el.firstChild.data('id')=j;
```

Just to clarify  - a bit of HTML:

```
<div id="5" class="textarea_cloned">
<textarea name="txt_5">Textarea 5</textarea>
<div class="remove" data-id="5"> X </div>
</div>
```

Thank you

Comment: Data values cannot be changed by default, even though you can, it will not retrieve the value. Treating `data-id` as an attribute, though, can change its value

Comment: Please [use the search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjavascript%5D+%5Bdom%5D+set+data+attribute): [Set data attribute using JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11286661/218196)

Comment: @Felix, I did...always do so, sire. I've just checked the search results and was unable to find the info guys have provided here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This-

Use `firstElementChild` instead of `firstChild`

The difference between this property and `firstChild`, is that `firstChild` returns the first child node as an **element node, a text node or a comment node** (depending on which one's first), while `firstElementChild` returns the first child node as an **element node (ignores text and comment nodes)**.

```
 el.firstElementChild.dataset.id=j
```

### DEMO

https://jsfiddle.net/vikrant47/frcqb42q/

`dataset` property of `dom` holds a map of all data attributes of dom.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to reflect it in HTML code then use [`setAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) method to set an attribute. Although you need to use [`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/firstElementChild) to get the element otherwise the `textNode` (whitespace at the beginning) may get as [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild).

```
 el.firstElementChild.setAttribute('data-id', j)
```

```js
var j = 10,
  el = document.getElementById('5');
el.firstElementChild.setAttribute('data-id', j)

console.log(el.innerHTML)
```

```html
<div id="5" class="textarea_cloned">
  <textarea name="txt_5">Textarea 5</textarea>
  <div class="remove" data-id="5">X</div>
</div>
```

---

If you just want to add in [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) property then set the property in [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset).

```
el.firstElementChild.dataset.id = j
```