# What is the difference between `firstChild` and `firstElementChild`?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

What is the difference between `firstChild` and `firstElementChild`?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41196036 explains the differences between `firstElementChild` and `firstChild`

Answer (score 26):

The difference boils down to the difference between a [`Node`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node) and an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element).
Every Element is also a Node, but a Node can also be a Text node, a Comment node, or something else.

[`firstElementChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Element/firstElementChild) returns the first child *Element* node, whereas [`firstChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild) returns the first child *Node*, regardless of whether it’s an Element, a Text, a Comment, or something else.

In the example below, you can see that `firstChild` returns the Comment node or Text node and `firstElementChild` always returns the Element child i.e. `<li>A</li>`.
Look into your browser console (<kbd>F12</kbd>) to see the results.

```js
const example1 = document.querySelector("ul.example1"),
  example2 = document.querySelector("ul.example2");

console.log(example1.firstChild); // #text "\n  "
console.log(example1.firstElementChild); // <li>A</li>
console.log(example2.firstChild); // <!--  This is a comment node.  -->
console.log(example2.firstElementChild); // <li>X</li>
```

```html
<ul class="example1">
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
<ul class="example2"><!-- This is a comment node. -->
  <li>X</li>
  <li>Y</li>
  <li>Z</li>
</ul>
```

If you’re wondering why `someElement.firstChild.appendChild` or `.innerHTML`, or `.addEventListener`, etc. doesn’t work — either doesn’t do anything or throws a TypeError —, then `someElement.firstChild` most likely is a Text node, which, unlike an Element node, doesn’t have any of these properties.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `firstElementChild` if your code is prettified.

[This example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild#Example:%7E:text=Example,-This) demonstrates the use of `firstChild` and how whitespace nodes might interfere with using this property.

Comment: _“if your code is prettified”_ — That’s very unclear and very misleading. You should use `firstElementChild` if you expect to receive an Element, not depending on some unrelated external circumstances such as formatting. There is no such thing as “whitespace nodes”; those are Text nodes. They also don’t “interfere” with this property: the entire _purpose_ of `firstChild` is to potentially find Text nodes.

Comment: @SebastianSimon Please make a PR to the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/firstChild#Example:%7E:text=Example,-This:~:text=firstChild%20and%20how-,whitespace%20nodes,-might%20interfere%20with) too