# Why adding new span make space between new span and previous ones and how to avoid this

Tags: javascript, html, css

So basically it makes "a +b=c". But I want to make "a+b=c".

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <span id="b__value">+b</span>
   <span id="c__value">=c</span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
const vlaueContainer = document.getElementsByClassName('timer__value')[0];
let newSpan = document.createElement('span');

newSpan.id = 'testId';
newSpan.innerHTML += "77";
valueContainer.insertBefore(newSpan, valueContainer.firstChild);
```

Comment: maybe the problem is what the `a` element could you show where and how that element is placed on the page

Comment: `valueContainer.insertBefore(newSpan, valueContainer.firstElementChild);` [What is the difference between \`firstChild\` and \`firstElementChild\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51280481)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, Inline Elements in HTML when used in different lines, (just as you did), are rendered on the page with a blank space between the elements.
If you want the output as expected, put the two elements in a single line, and not in different lines.

```
<div class="container">
   <span id="b__value">+b</span><span id="c__value">=c</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Yea :D 
Already found it couple minutes ago but still thank you a lot.