# Adding a table tag via JavaScript with a dashed parameter

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am trying to add a `Bootstrap Table` table tag with `Javascript`. One of the parameters for the table tag is `data-pagination`. This method of adding it, is failing due to the `-`.

How can I work around this?

Desired Output:

```
<table id="mytable" data-pagination="true" class="table table-striped"></table>
```

My code:

```
var table_div = document.createElement('table');
table_div.id = 'mytable';
table_div.className = "table table-striped";
table_div.data-pagination = "true";
document.body.appendChild(table_div);
```

Comment: You should use `.dataset`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set data attribute using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286661/set-data-attribute-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the **[`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)** in this case like :

```
table_div.dataset.pagination = true;
```

Code:

```js
var table_div = document.createElement('table');
table_div.id = 'mytable';
table_div.className = "table table-striped";
table_div.dataset.pagination = "true";
document.body.appendChild(table_div);

console.log(document.body.innerHTML)
```

Answer (score 1):

`table_div.setAttribute('data-pagination', 'true')`

Comment: Or `table_div.dataset.pagination = true`