# How can I set the data-src on an img with pure JS?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to set a data-src attribute on an img I am creating with JS.

Why does this not work?

```
const image = document.createElement('img');
image.className = 'restaurant-img';
image.src = '/img/1.jpg';
image.data-src = DBHelper.imageUrlForRestaurant(restaurant);
li.append(image);
```

IDE says: Must be lvalue

So I cannot assign it.

How else can I set the data-src on an img then from pure JavaScript (no jQuery);

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set data attribute using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11286661/set-data-attribute-using-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to set an *attribute*, you should use `setAttribute`.

Like this:

```js
const image = document.createElement('img');
image.className = 'restaurant-img';
image.src = '/img/1.jpg';
image.setAttribute('data-src', 'foobar');
document.body.appendChild(image);
console.log(image.outerHTML);
```

If you wanted to set the element's *property name* of `data-src`, you would have to use bracket notation, because `-` is an illegal character in dot notation:

```
image['data-src'] = 'foobar';
```